# How do you operate an "up 3" split dx station with a Kenwood TS570 or similar HF radio?

Tags: kenwood, equipment-operation, split-frequency, ts570s

My Kenwood has "split" and "rit/xit". Is the "split" mode suitable for operating a split for a DX pileup situation, where a station is listening "3 up"?

I'm confused about which of the larger or smaller frequencies on my screen, or the letters A and B, is the receive and which is transmit, in split mode?  How do I know which is my receive and which is my transmit in RIT/XIT mode?

Am I the only one who reads the manual and is left without a clue here?

In split mode I have no idea if the larger frequency value is both my listen and transmit frequency and I have to press A/B, talk, then press A/B again, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at a TS-570 manual right now.  This is pretty standard split operations.

Select the transmit VFO (press A/B to choose), set the transmit frequency as desired (in your case, operating freq +3).  Then press A/B to select the receive VFO and set the operating frequency.  THEN push the split button. When you transmit, your transceiver will essentially automatically switch VFOs for you, transmit, and switch back.  You should see the frequency change when you transmit, then go back when you finish.

[image: PTT button up and down affect on Split display]

Comment: I guess I need it all drawn out with a pretty picture, and the manual didn't make it clear to me which number means what.  So when NOT transmitting, the larger LCD display frequency is my listen and the smaller VFO frequency display is the one it will switch to when I transmit.  I feel a bit dumb even asking. :-)

Comment: Yes, if your main VFO (large numbers) sayd 14.200, and your other VFO (small numbers) is set to 14.210 AND your SPLIT indicator is on, then you are going to transmit on 14.210, receive on 14.200, and you don't have to go pushing A/B a lot.
Look at this image for instance
[link](http://www.universal-radio.com/catalog/hamhf/1862lrg.gif)

Comment: I added that picture + my own edits to the pic. Someone please accept my edit!